# Challenging exercises for proof correctness

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, proof-techniques, correctness-proof

I would like to know where I can find challenging exercises that ask to prove the correctness of an algorithm.

The invariant of most of the exercises I’ve found on the internet are quite easy (factorial, binomial coefficients...).

That’s why I was wondering if there exist a book or some online ressources where I can find challenging proof correctness’s exercises ?

Thank you !

Comment: *Programming: The Derivation of Algorithms* by Kaldewaij ;-)

Comment: @MusaAl-hassy Didn’t know that book :) If you have time can you provide an example of exercise in this book ? :-)

Comment: Surprisingly, when I searched "proof" or "prove" in the search bar on the top left of this page, the questions returned by the search is roughly described by "most of the exercises I’ve found on the internet are quite easy". (Well, it is not surprising at all once I took a moment to think.)

Comment: Since you did not state your background, I will assume you are not very much into algorithms yet. You can read the most popular book _Introduction to Algorithms_ by CLRS (four people here). There are plenty of exercises in that books that is much harder than the internet average.

Comment: Now that I had offered my opinion, I voted to close this question as "primarily opinion-based"

Comment: @Thinking The text begins with a specification of the problem, then brings in formality when necessary, then **derives** code which is then correct by construction! E.g., include standard sorting algorithms as well as heap sort, classical loop problems, as well as 2-dimensional array probelms such as saddle sort ;-)